# Only Weyl group of rank two root system can be dihedral

Tags: root-systems, weyl-group

Let $\Phi$ be a (reduced, crystallographic) root system, and $W$ its Weyl group.
Is it possible to prove that if we know $W$ is dihedral, then the rank of $\Phi$ is two, ***Without*** using the classification of root system, but only elementary facts? (In Humphreys' Lie Algebras book, this correspond to ch. 9-10)
(It can be assumed that $\Phi$ is irreducible)

**Remark:** My failed attempts so far:

1. In dihedral group there are at most two elements of order two that commute with each other  (Only reflections of two perpendicular roots commute) - However, not every root system of rank greater than two has three perpendicular roots.
2. Dihedral groups are generated just by two elements of order two - It turns out that also the symmetric group can be generated by two elements of order two.
3. I thought, in similar vein, to show that if dihedral group is generated by three elements of order two then it can be generated by two of these elements - This is simply wrong, since for example the group $D_{2\cdot 30}$ with reflection $s$ and rotation $t$ of order 30 is generated by the three elements $s,st^2,st^5$ but no two of them generate the group.

---

**Edit:** If a group can be generated by two non-commuting elements of order two the it is dihedral as shown for example [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf). (The symmetric group can be generated by [*three*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462472/number-of-involutions-generating-symmetric-group) elements of order two.)

So to show the claim it suffices to show that if the rank of $\Phi$ is greater than two, then $W$ cannot be generated by two elements of order two. For reflections it can be deduced easily from the transitivity of Weyl chambers (since a reflection fixes codimension 1 subspace) but it is not clear how to show the claim for general elements.

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies as elementary, but you can use the fact that absolutelt irreducible representations of dihedral groups have dimension at most 2.

Comment: Re last sentence, maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/357588/96384

Comment: @MoisheKohan Since I haven't found another route, can you elaborate on your comment as an answer? I think that it's fairly easy to show that the original (real) vector space (which $\Phi$ spans) is irreducible rep. of $W$. how we get from complex reps. to real reps.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Moishe Kohan comment, I was able to find a proof, with the following steps:

1. If $\Phi$ is reducible, then it is fairly easy to show that the Weyl Group is a product of the corresponding Weyl groups. The only dihedral group which is a product is $D_4\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, and the root system is $A_1\times A_1$, which is of rank 2.
   So we can assume onwards that $\Phi$ is irreducible.
2. The Weyl group $W$ acts on $V$ (the real vector space which $\Phi$ span). Since $\Phi$ is irreducible, $V$ is irreducible representation of $W$. (This claim is present in Humphreys, but can be shown quite easily).
3. Now, the scalar extension $V_\mathbb{C}$ is (complex) irreducible representation of $W$. Thanks to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/380611/40779), the only non-elementary ingredient in the proof is the scalar extension itself.
4. every complex irreducible representation of a dihedral group is 1- or 2-dimensional: the group is generated by reflection $s$ and rotation $t$. Choose an eigenvector of $t$, so because $V$ is irreducible it is the span of $v$ and $s\cdot v$.
   Since the dimension of $V$ is equal to the complex dimension of $V_\mathbb{C}$, the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that it is not true that the symmetric group can be generated by two elements of order 2 (except in the case $n = 3$, which is dihedral).  "Can be generated by two elements of order 2" is a classification of dihedral groups (if you include the infinite dihedral group $\langle s, t \mid s^2 = t^2 = 1\rangle$).

Comment: This is more a (correct) comment than an answer I think.